# How to see thrown exceptions with jasmine-node?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm having trouble seeing exceptions thrown when I test code with `jasmine-node`. I've tried the `--captureExceptions` flag with no luck.

Minimal example:

#### test/mySpec.js

```
var r = require('./badness.js')
describe("things:", function(){
  it("can", function(){
    expect(r()).toBe("work")
  })
})
```

#### test/badness.js

```
module.exports = function(){
  throw "badness";
  return "work";
};
```

#### Try running jasmine

```
npm install jasmine-node --save-dev
$ ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine-node --captureExceptions test/
F

Failures:

  1) things: can
   Message:
     badness
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 0.004 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

I would have expected a stack trace or indication of *where* the error was thrown from. Is this possible / excepted? A bug, or my incorrect expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As everything in JavaScript it depends on the JavaScript engine, I would say that most moderns engine implementing V8 are cool with Error exception. Try this:

```
throw new Error('Error with better stacktrace');
```

Also, instead of look in the console, try to use the Jasmine matcher "toThrow".

```
it("The 'toThrow' matcher is for testing if a function throws an exception", function() {
  var foo = function() {
    return 1 + 2;
  };
  var bar = function() {
    return a + 1;
  };

  expect(foo).not.toThrow();
  expect(bar).toThrow();
});
```